# Magento does not refresh static block cache automatically

Tags: php, magento, caching

I am using Magento 1.9.2 and I am facing static block cache problem. How this problem raises, is given below in steps. (As I am new to magento so please try to understand what I want to say, may be my words are different)

I have three pages with three categories Women, Men, Kids. On every category detail page I assigned two static blocks to show banners and offers relative to the category. If I open first time (lets say) women category page, it shows me all banners related to women category but when I open men or kids page it doesn't show me relative content instead it shows me women category. When I flush magento cache and reload the page it shows me right content but when I travel to other page it shows me again old or non related content.

I followed many articles to over ride this problem but failed, mainly I tried;

https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/71705/cms-block-caching-issue-in-ee-1-14-2

http://blog.gaiterjones.com/magento-1-9-2-0-ce-static-block-cache-bug/
(cache is important for me when following this link instructions)

Any help from SO!

Comment: You can disable block cache from xml: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39439646/magento-xml-layout-update-with-cache-enabled/39453273#39453273

Answer (score 1):

its a very common issue in magento you just need to download this extension from the below link and set it to true in app/etc/modules/Milopole_Cms.xml
https://www.milople.com/blogs/ecommerce/solved-magento-static-block-display-issue.html

Comment: You can disable the Block/Html cache from cache management in admin. But its not a good idea to disable. This is the only way to get rid of it. If above mentioned extension doesn't work