# Magento xml layout update with cache enabled

Tags: xml, magento, caching

In my magento store I want to display a different footer in cart page. So I created a second file (myfooter.phtml) and I placed in checkout.xml the following layout update:

```
<reference name="footer">
<action method="setTemplate"><template>page/html/myfooter.phtml</template></action>
</reference>
```

Everything works like a charm with cache disabled but when I enable BLOCK_HTML cache (Blocks HTML output) from admin panel I get the original footer.phtml

A partial solution is to disable the BLOCK_HTML cache, but tis makes my store slow.

Any idea would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<action method="setCacheLifetime"><lifetime>1</lifetime></action>
```

Comment: Thank you! Until now works like a charm with a small modification:<action method="setCacheLifetime"></action>. If you set <lifetime> node does not work properly (at least in my case)

Comment: It's 1.9.2.4 Also I found this article http://fbrnc.net/blog/2015/06/cache-and-layout-xml-tricks

Comment: Or you can do in template: 

        $this->addData(array('cacheLifetime'=>true));